# Can't uninstall apps that are being used on wine

Tags: wine

I recently installed wine so that I could play midtown madness 2 on it but when I installed midtown madness and ran it, it crashed so now I want to uninstall it but I can't is there a way I can get rid of midtown madness? I am running ububtu 12.04.

Answer (score 1):

Wine has an interface for uninstalling software, just run `winecfg`. If this doesn't work, you could remove the .wine directory in your home folder, but this will remove any program installed using wine.

I think you should also take a look at playonlinux. It provides you with the possibility to use different wine versions for different programs and easily uninstall software as each program has it's own environment which can be deleted as a whole so you don't have to uninstall any software.

Comment: Yeah how do I do that,

Comment: under the number 0 with the up and down arrow is a button to do that

Comment: @Goku As you are a new member of askubuntu and new to the stackexchange network, I hereby want to welcome you in the name of the community!